# How to Post Data before Pop-Up?

Tags: angularjs, popup, window.open

I have an application where the user can edit content, then preview that content. Before preview, I need to have the content saved ($http.post to the server). I'm using angular and because the save routine is run through a different controller the code to save looks like:

```
$scope.$broadcast('save');
var saveCompletedListener = $scope.$on('saveCompleted', function () {
    // this call doesn't work (because it waits for data save):
    window.open($scope.contentUrl);
});

// this call does work, but shows old data in the popup:
window.open($scope.contentUrl);
```

The problem is the window.open call is getting blocked in all browsers. If I just call the window.open without waiting for save, it opens fine (it just shows the content from the previous save). So, is there some way in angular to show the popup, but have it wait to load the url until save has completed?

Comment: Can you add the listener for the save event? Are both events in the same scope?

Comment: @ruedamanuel That actually wouldn't matter. Even running a standard $http call here won't work. For the moment I pop up a dialog in a div tag and force the user to click "Preview" again. That gets around the blockers because the user has just clicked and the window.open happens immediately after. This does make the interface a bit clunky though.

Comment: What I wanted to see is if there's any reason why the 'save' event wouldn't be listened to. If they're not part of the same controller you should be using $rootScope.$broadcast instead of $scope or else you won't be able to listen when the 'save' event is fired.

Comment: @ruedamanuel I think I see. Unless I don't understand you - save works fine - the issue is with the popup after the save completes.

Comment: are you broadcasting the 'saveCompleted' event from the success callback of the $http.post that I assume you're using to save?

Comment: try broadcasting the saveCompleted event to $rootScope instead of $scope and not casting the listener in a variable i.e. $scope.$on(...); instead of var saveCompletedListener = $scope.$on(...);